# How to build OpenEXR using cmake for windows 7 VS2013

Tags: openexr

I have encountered problem in building a solution of OpenEXR using Cmake for VS2013.

FYI, i have installed the prerequisite of OpenEXR, ILMBase and specify the path in system path variables. However, when i configure Cmake to produce solution for VS2013, the ILMBase package prefix cant be located.

Is there any solution to this??

[image]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

if you still have the problem: Follow the readme, so don't use the cmake gui, but type everything in the command line (which includes specifying ILMBASE_PACKAGE_PREFIX)